# Is there any way to detect if the browsers cache is cleared

Tags: javascript, browser-cache, session-storage

Is there any way to detect if the browsers cache is cleared , I want to check this on a javascript application and I am using session storage.

Example:
I am on page 1.
i do some operations, like edit a field ..etc
i clear the cache.
Can i get to know that cache is cleared , when i am still on page 1. i use session storage.

I understand , the storage event will let us identify any modification on the session storage when the current tab is closed and new tab is opened.

but i want to set a flag or throw an alert message whenever the cache of the current browser is cleared.

Please help!

Comment: clear the storage on page load using localStorage.clear() and then set the counter to 0. this will work only if using localStorage for storing count. Elaborate more from where you referring count if this is not the case

Comment: Where are you getting the count? Are you getting from the sevre through the ajax call or are you storing in the session?

Comment: Please post code to where this stuff is calculated etc, as this questions stands i feel it is too broad.

Comment: addToCart : function(event) {
var self = this;
$("#itemCount").css('display','block');    if(sessionStorage.getItem("cartItemArray")) {    self.cartItemArray=JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("cartItemArray"))
}, ---> this is my code where i handle the count

Comment: Thank you for all your suggestions, but ive edited my question. please help me find a solution for the edited question. TIA

Answer (score 0):

I dont know straight way, but this may help:

```
if (!localStorage.length && !sessionStorage.length) {
    // No items in localStorage and in sessionStorage,
    // cache possibly cleared
    [your code here]
}
```